# Angular 10 routing on new component always the same

Tags: angular

I have two components:

The default `app` component, which resolves to `/` and

a new `contactwish` component, which resolves to `/contactwish`.

In `app-routing.module.ts` I have added the new `contactwish` component:

```
import { ContactwishComponent } from './contactwish/contactwish.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'contactwish',
    component:ContactwishComponent
  }
];
```

I now defined a `routerLink` in `app.component.html`:

```
<a routerLink="contactwish"> Weiter </a>
```

I have also defined a `routerLink` in `contactwish.component.html`:

```
<a routerLink="/"> Zurück </a>
```

**The Problem**

If I start the app I can see the button `Weiter`. I can click it and it will load `/contactwish`, so this seems to work. BUT under `/contactwish` I do not see the `Zurück` button. I see the same button, which I clicked. It looks like I am still on `/`.

**Questions**

I am new to Angular and have some more questions to this topic.

1. In one tutorial I saw a guy use `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. I tried to google it, but I cant find a good explanation of what it does, so I removed it. With `router-outlet` it also did not work, maybe I must use it? Do I have to use it once or in every component?
2. Adding new components to `app-routing.module.ts` is important for routing, but I did not add `app.component.ts`. I simply wrote `routerLink="/"`. Is this the correct way to create a route back to the homepage?`
3. How to solve the problem above?

Thanks to everyone who takes the time to look at this question.

**EDIT**

If I add `router-outlet` in `app.component.html` and `contactwish.component.html`:

[image]

I see both views now in `/contactwish`, but I want to see only `Zurück`

Comment: share some code from your component where you update Weiter/Zuruck buttons and how you do this

Comment: Please give a [mre]. I'd recommend reading through e.g. https://angular.io/guide/router, or https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5.

Comment: @all That is all the code I have written into my angular project. All the other code is the default code when you create an angular project. Shall I add the default code, which comes with angular? Seems weird. The question will become HUGE.

Answer (score 1):

First, routing error shows mostly on the console log, so try to retrieve what's happening.
You may want to check this example [this example](https://vegibit.com/angular-routing-example/) out, I'm sure it will guide you.
**Router Outlet ** tag is like a routing point in which your components will load dynamically, of course using the router (so yeah, without it you won't see anything displayed).
Hope I helped even a bit, happy coding :)

Comment: My pleasure, you may want to check that router outlet if existing, the router module is importer and the routes are well defined (tbh, these are the most frequent problem to happen).

Comment: I think the problem is that the routing system is not capable of switching views completely, which is really sad. The defined buttons MUST be always displayed.